# solrj QueryResponse getTermsResponse returns null

Tags: json, scala, solrj, word-frequency

I'm trying to get a TermsResponse object from a solrj QueryResponse object, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I'm using scala, but I would be happy with a working java example too.

First I set up the term vector query, which looks to be working:

```
val solrurl = "http://localhost:8983/solr"
val server= new HttpSolrServer( solrurl )
val query = new SolrQuery
query.setRequestHandler("/tvrh")
query.set("fl", "text")
query.set("tv.all", true)
query.setQuery("uid:" + id)
val response = server.query(query)
```

The query returns a QueryResponse object whose toString looks to be a JSON object.  This object includes the term vector information (terms, frequency, etc . . .) as part of the JSON object.

But when I do this I always get a null object:

```
val termsResponse = Option(response.getTermsResponse)
```

Is this function deprecated?

If so what is the best way to retrieve the structure from QueryResponse?  Convert to JSON?  Some other sources point to using response.get("termVector") but that seems to be deprecated.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have been using simple java object for this with the following configuration.

```
    //Adding terms for 2 word phrases
    qterms.setTerms(true);
    qterms.setRequestHandler("/terms");
    qterms.setTermsLimit(20);
    qterms.addTermsField("PhraseIndx2");
    qterms.setTermsMinCount(20);

    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();

    //queryresponse get all terms from in 2 phrase field
    System.out.println ("printing the terms from queryresponse: \n");
    QueryResponse resTerms = solr.query(qterms);
    TermsResponse termResp =resTerms.getTermsResponse();
    List<Term> terms = termResp.getTerms("PhraseIndx2");
    System.out.print(terms.size());
```